# MVP Taligent Programming Model for .Net

Tags: model-view-controller, mvp, composite-controls

Has anyone created a `.NET` control architecture using the [taligent programming model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taligent) as follows?

http://www.wildcrest.com/Potel/Portfolio/mvp.pdf

As stated by IBM -

> MVP will enable IBM to deliver a unified conceptual programming model across all its major object-oriented language environments

The question is how do you implement or map the IInteractor concept (Page 9) to a .NET interface? Currently the guess is to use the `IInputElement` interface as a the event source for all UI input controls.

If anyone has already implemented the taligent pattern in .NET, I would like to know if it is applies to both Silverlight and WPF. If so, does it apply to the union of their interfaces?

Finally this represents the unified abstract architecture and can displace `PresentationFramework.dll`. If you see this applies as a control architecture, please comment.

Comment: A hint - using meaningless terms like "unified fractal abstract architecture" is not going to win you many friends here.

Comment: Well let me help you understand the concept it's a abstract (meaning written using interfaces) unified meaning the interfaces are common across all devleopment platforms (siliverlight, wpf, mobile) and finally fractal based meaning it's the same pattern on all levels or true composition. Understand?

Comment: That's not any definition of the word "fractal" i've ever read.  In fact, just the opposite.  Fractal comes from the latin Fractus, meaning Fractured or broken.  So i'd avoid the condescending tone.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you mean by ".net".  The term covers many kinds of applications.  Web apps, Web Services, Windows Forms apps, WPF apps, etc...

MVP is used a lot in ASP.NET Web apps.  See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188690.aspx

Comment: You don't get it. A unified architecture would compile to all those

Comment: Not really.  There is an inherant difference between a stateful and stateless architecture, ala web vs GUI.  It would be quite difficult, and likely highly inefficient to try and unify them.

Comment: Actually web and gui are converging. You just dont see it man. Sorry.

Comment: Of course they are converging.  But that doesn't mean they can be treated the same from a programming perspective.  They are fundamentally different backend concepts, even if you treat them the same on the front-end.

Comment: No they are not. You are confusing REST with RPC

Answer (score 0):

The article [How to: Implement the Model-View-Presenter Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304879.aspx) of the MSDN [patterns & practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998572.aspx) section seams to be what you are looking for...

Comment: Thank you for the comment however this does not address a number of interfaces in the taligent pattern such as ISelection, ICommandOn<> and IInteractor. Basically no one is doing this right now and it will displace PresentationFramework.dll (puke layer) leaving PresentationCore.dll or System.windows

Answer (score 0):

We have created a complete MVP framework for .NET, based on the Taligent ideas. It took us some time to get right but now we can create applications by writing business classes, creating a new form and drag-dropping the properties of a class onto the form.

The framework is very sophisticated and allows for the customisation of forms at runtime, as well as automatically hooking up validation in the business classes to edits on the form.

We also wrote an OPF (Object Persistence Framework) to complement it, so avoiding the need to manage database code as well.

Comment: Hey I am very interested to know a few of the details. Care to talk offline? t